# C++ memory management in struct of references

Tags: c++, struct, reference

I'm new to C++ and trying to understand what (if anything) needs to be done to safely free the memory allocated in a struct of references. Here's a simplified example:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

typedef struct dist {
  const arma::colvec& mu;
  const arma::mat& Sigma;
  dist(const arma::colvec& mu, const arma::mat& Sigma): mu(mu), Sigma(Sigma) {}; 
} dist;

arma::mat test_struct(const arma::vec& my_vector, const::arma& my_matrix, const int iter = 1000) {
  for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
    dist d(my_vector, my_matrix);
    // Some other things here
  }
  // Some other things here
}
```

In the for loop of the `test_struct` function, I understand that each struct goes out of scope at the end of the iteration in which it was created and is freed, but what needs to be done about the references to objects from the Armadillo library? Are the destructors for the two referenced objects automatically called, or do I need to do something else to prevent a memory leak? Or do I need to provide a destructor in the struct?

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Just a note, in C++, there is no need to typedef structs. `struct TypeName {};` is enough.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm new to C++ and trying to understand what (if anything) needs to be done to safely free the memory allocated in a struct of references.

**Nothing at all**, since there is no memory being allocated dynamically, so there is nothing to free.

> In the for loop of the test_struct function, I understand that each struct goes out of scope at the end of the iteration in which it was created and is freed

Correct.  Each loop iteration creates and destroys a new instance of the struct.

> what needs to be done about the references to objects from the Armadillo library?

Nothing at all.

> Are the destructors for the two referenced objects automatically called

No, because they weren't constructed here, so they do not need to be destructed here.  A reference is just an alias to an existing object.  You don't destroy an object just because you have a reference to it.  You destroy the object only when it is no longer being used.  An object created in *automatic* storage is destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope.  An object created in *dynamic* storage is destroyed only when explicitly requested to be destroyed, such as by calling `delete`.

> do I need to do something else to prevent a memory leak?

There is no memory leak in this code.

> do I need to provide a destructor in the struct?

No.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to do anything about the references.

The memory they represent isn't owned by the struct, and doesn't need to be managed in any way.

> Are the destructors for the two referenced objects automatically called, or do I need to do something else to prevent a memory leak?

The destructors of the referenced objects will be called, when these go out of scope or are `delete`d from dynamically allocated memory.

> Or do I need to provide a destructor in the struct?

No, as mentioned above, that's not necessary.